# Spring Data JPA: duplicate records after sorting by a property in a joined table

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have faced one trouble in my project, therefore I will provide an example using a demo project. Imagine there are two entities: teacher and student.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHERS")
public class Teacher  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters

}
```

There is a repository and a service class:

```
public interface TeacherRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Teacher, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Teacher> {
}
```

```
@Service
public class TeacherService {

    @Autowired
    private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherToDTOMapper teacherToDTOMapper;

    public Page<TeacherDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Teacher> specification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("id"), 2);
        };
        return teacherRepository.findAll(specification, pageable).map(teacherToDTOMapper::mapEntityToDTO);
    }
}
```

And, finally, a controller class:

```
@RestController
public class TeacherController {

    @Autowired
    private TeacherService teacherService;

    @GetMapping("/teachers")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public PagedModel<EntityModel<TeacherDTO>> findAll(PagedResourcesAssembler<TeacherDTO> resourcesAssembler, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<TeacherDTO> page = teacherService.findAll(pageable);
        return resourcesAssembler.toModel(page);
    }
}
```

On UI there is a [table of teachers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WisJw.png).

A user filters out teachers having id > 2 and sorts them by names of their students. The expected result should contain Aliyah Wiggins and Macy Reyes exactly in that order (because a student Amina Parks should be the first after sorting).
http://localhost:8080/teachers?page=0&size=3&sort=students.name,asc

However, actual result is:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "teacherDTOList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aliyah",
        "surname": "Wiggins",
        "students": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Amina",
            "surname": "Parks"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Caleb",
            "surname": "Baker"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Valentino",
            "surname": "Kent"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Jaron",
            "surname": "Luna"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Cayden",
            "surname": "Hoover"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Aliyah",
        "surname": "Wiggins",
        "students": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Amina",
            "surname": "Parks"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Caleb",
            "surname": "Baker"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Valentino",
            "surname": "Kent"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Jaron",
            "surname": "Luna"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Cayden",
            "surname": "Hoover"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Macy",
        "surname": "Reyes",
        "students": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Jasmin",
            "surname": "Friedman"
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Randall",
            "surname": "Archer"
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Caroline",
            "surname": "Davila"
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Sarah",
            "surname": "Pace"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/teachers?page=0&size=3&sort=students.name,asc"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 3,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

There are duplicate records for Aliyah Wiggins. I have not found an appropriate way how to get the expected result, so now I am thinking that searching of objects related to one entity with sorting by property in another entity is not right.
The demo project is available [here](https://github.com/tyoma17/duplicate-records-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to think that trying to sort teachers (i.e. 'One' in One-To-Many relationship) by students' (i.e.'Many') names is wrong. We will get the following result after an attempt to sort by students' names:

```
ROW    TEACHER_NAME     TEACHER_SURNAME     STUDENT_FULL_NAME
1      Evan             Fuentes             Allyson Noble
2      Aliyah           Wiggins             Amina Parks
3      Evan             Fuentes             Ashlyn Berg
4      Aliyah           Wiggins             Caleb Baker
...
```

A teacher could be first, third and the last one at the same time. Hence, that king of sorting is meaningless.
Moreover, Many-To-Many fits better in the example, but still does not change the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You can use named entity graph to avoid duplicate records.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Teacher.students" ,attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("students"))
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHERS")
public class Teacher  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters

}
```

And overide the findAll method as

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Teacher.students" , type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
Page<Teacher> findAll(Specification<Teacher> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank you, entity graphs are interesting feature, however, it didn't help in my real project. In the demo I have only one one-to-many relation in Teacher class, but in the real one there are 3 such relations. Those tables have > 100k records. The entity graph approach returns cartesian product and does not take into account pagination, so there are >400k records. It takes more than a minute to display a content of one page.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the query to return distinct values in the specification:

```
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
```

This is normally set to true by Spring Data on the `findAll` methods but it is not implied when you use your own specification. You are now seeing the results of the database join query (teacher will be repeated once for each student).

I suggest adding a flag property to the model instead of skipping by id. Introducing something like `hidden / deleted / private` would simplify the code and make it more readable. You could then use an empty repository interface method: `findByActiveTrue();`

Comment: criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("id"), 2);

Unfortunately, it didn't help:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Order by expression "STUDENTS1_.NAME" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:
select distinct teacher0_.id as id1_1_, teacher0_.name as name2_1_, teacher0_.surname as surname3_1_ from teachers teacher0_ left outer join students students1_ on teacher0_.id=students1_.teacher_id where teacher0_.id<=2 order by students1_.name asc limit ? [90068-200]

Comment: Error is caused by the fact that you are ordering by a column that is not in the select itself. I think you will have to do the ordering that you are after in code as it does not make much sense from a query point of view. You can add an @OrderBy("name") annotation to the Students list and sort the Teacher list based on teacher.getStudents().get(0) (if I understood the requirement right).

Also, shouldn't it be >=2 ?